# Hierarchical Treeview Categories Write Side by Side

Tags: php, laravel, treeview, categories

I have hierarchical categories. I want to print them in a table. I want it to write Subcategory and main category in each row of the table.
**Example :** 
Electronics
Electronics > Computer
Electronics > Computer > Accessories
Electronics > Computer > Accessories -> Mouse
Electronics > Computer > Accessories -> Keyboard
Cosmetics 
Cosmetics > Skin Care
Cosmetics > Skin Care > Skin Cream
Cosmetics > Skin Care > Skin Mask

I tried this function. It didn't work.

```
public function getSubCats($Categories)
    {
        foreach($Categories as $category){
            if(count($category->subcategory)){
                $this->getSubCats($category->subcategory);
                return $category->subcategory;
            }else{
                return $category->subcategory;
            }
        }
    }
```

Categories database table

| id | parent_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Electronics |
| 2 | 1 | Computers |
| 3 | 2 | Accessories |
| 4 | 3 | Keyboards |
| 5 | NULL | Cosmetics |
| 6 | 5 | Skin Care |
| 7 | 6 | Skin Cream |
| 8 | 7 | Skin Mask |

Index blade categories table (Subcategory No limit)

| Category Name | Action |
| --- | --- |
| Electronics | Edit |
| Electronics - Computers | Edit |
| Electronics - Computers - Accessories | Edit |
| Electronics - Computers - Accessories - Keyboards | Edit |
| Cosmetics | Edit |
| Cosmetics - Skin Care | Edit |
| Cosmetics - Skin Care - Skin Cream | Edit |
| Cosmetics - Skin Care - Skin Mask | Edit |

Can you help me.
Thank you.

Comment: how is your source data stored?

Comment: @Erik categories table columns id, name, parent_id

Comment: can you update your original question with some example data?

Comment: Do you know the max depth of the categories?

Comment: The maximum depth of the categories is unlimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 0 (zero) instead of NULL to determine top level categories because of the difference in getting results from MySQL.

```
where column = 1/2/3/4
```

vs

```
where column is NULL
```

When using 0 (zero) I can use the same prepared statement.

This is what I came up with:

```
function get_cat_by_parent( $pdo, $id ) {
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM stackoverflow.categories WHERE parent_id = ?";
    $stmt   = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
    try {
        $stmt->execute([$id]);
        $data   = $stmt->fetchALL( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
    } catch (PDOException $e ) {
        // exception
    }
    return $data;
}

function recursive( $pdo, $array, $depth, $label ) {
    $depth++;
    $data   = get_cat_by_parent( $pdo, $array['id'] );
    if(count($data)) {
        foreach( $data as $row) {
            echo $label;
            echo " &#x2192; ";
            echo $row['name'];
            echo "<br />";
            recursive( $pdo, $row, $depth, $label . " &#x2192; " . $row['name'] );
        }
    }
}

$parents    = get_cat_by_parent( $pdo, 0 );
foreach( $parents as $row ) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "<br />";
    recursive( $pdo, $row, 0, $row['name'] );
}
```

Output:

```
Electronics
Electronics → Computers
Electronics → Accessories
Electronics → Accessories → USB Hub
Electronics → Accessories → Memory Card Readers
Electronics → Accessories → Mic Stand
Electronics → Keyboards
Cosmetics
Cosmetics → Skin Care
Cosmetics → Skin Cream
Cosmetics → Skin Cream → Oil of Olaz
Cosmetics → Skin Cream → Something
Cosmetics → Skin Cream → Other
Cosmetics → Skin Mask
```

I added a few more categories to your test data.

Comment: $parents    = get_cat_by_parent( $pdo, 0 );  I am using laravel. What can I use instead of $pdo.

Comment: You can use whatever laravel offers, it's not important. I've never used laravel so not much help there, sorry